# waveOutGetVolume() always returns 4294967295 (max value)

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, volume

Help please, why the function always returns the maximum number 4294967295 despite the change in volume in the system? What am I doing wrong?

My system is Windows XP SP3 x86.

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
    private static extern int waveOutGetVolume(IntPtr hwo, out uint dwVolume);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        uint currVol;
        int result = waveOutGetVolume(IntPtr.Zero, out currVol);
        if (result != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Some error occured...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("currVol = {0}", currVol); //always = 4294967295
        ushort left_channel_volume = (ushort)(currVol & 0xffff);
        Console.WriteLine("left_channel_volume = {0}", left_channel_volume); //always = 65535
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `hwo` is optional? The docs don't indicate that to be the case

Comment: As Alex K. pointed out you certainly must something else than 0 in hmo, that is a handle obtained via the waveOutOpen function.

Comment: Alex K., yes. I'm being quite sure, because the first parameter indicates the number of audio device. And I have it only one, so the first parameter is zero. I also watched a lot of examples of the use of this function in the Internet and everywhere here often pass zero. But I do not understand why this function does not working for me...

Comment: Michael Walz, I would be very grateful if you show an example of how to do it?

Comment: `waveOutGetVolume()` accepts an open device handle **or** a device ID as input. Device ID 0 is valid for input if there is at least 1 audio device present.

Comment: Isn't `IntPtr.Zero` marshalled as `NULL` rather than zero?

Comment: According to Microsoft, hwo is "Handle to an open waveform-audio output device. This parameter can also be a device identifier." IIRC, 0 as uDeviceID means the default device. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mmeapi/nf-mmeapi-waveoutgetvolume

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers. I have not received the correct answer. I myself have found the cause of this behavior. The problem turned out to be quite different.

These function do not directly affect hardware settings. In addition, this is associated with a process-specific audio session, so changes affect the calling application but do not affect other applications...

Check the correctness of this can be something like this:

1. Call waveOutSetVolume (0, 0x0) for each / main device;
2. Call waveOutGetVolume and get the correct result, while in the system mixer volume icon will appear in the application with a volume control.